# Add taxonomy Term to WooCommerce product permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, permalinks

I want to add the slug of a custom taxonomy to the permalink of a WooCommerce product. To do this, I've added a taxonomy called brand. Now I want to add the slug of the brand to the product url.

**Before:**
www.shop.com/product/product-name/

**After:**
www.shop.com/product/brand-product-name/

I've done some research and found the following tutorial for something like that: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-taxonomy-term-custom-post-permalinks-wordpress/

But I don't add the Custom Post Type "WooCommerce procuct" by myself so I don't know how to add the rewrite code from here:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects/%projectscategory%', 'with_front' => false),`

EDIT: Here's my custom code:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'productbrand_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function productbrand_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if (false !== strpos($post_link, '%brand%')) {
        $productbrand_type_term = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'brand');
        if (!empty($productbrand_type_term))
            $post_link = str_replace('%brand%', array_pop($productbrand_type_term)->
            slug, $post_link);
        else
            $post_link = str_replace('%brand%', 'uncategorized', $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

The problem is, that the URL looks like this:

www.shop.com/product/brand-/product-name/

Is there any way to remove the `/` after the `brand-`

In my custom base inside the permalik option I added the following:

```
/product/%brand%-
```

But it always adds the `/` to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it might be easier than you think.

Just visit Settings > Permalinks and scroll down to **Product permalinks** and set the **Custom base** with `/product/%product_cat%/` and you're done.

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Comment: Thanks, but it’s not the product category. It’s a custom taxonomy

Comment: then that my answer to your first problem along this line `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects/%projectscategory%', 'with_front' => false),`

Comment: you can follow the instructions on the link you provided. just put the rewrite part on the **Custom base**

Comment: thanks, I updated my question with my custom code. But there is still a `/` before the product name

Comment: use something like `/product/%brand%/` and on replace use `$post_link = str_replace('%brand%/', array_pop($productbrand_type_term)->
            slug . '-', $post_link);`. I have not tried though